# Dartlang rxdart - merge different type streams

Tags: dart, flutter, rxdart

here is my use case:

I have two different `Observables`:

```
Observable<MobileAdEvent> adEventStream;
Observable<Color> colorStream;
```

I need to receive notification when **either** of those two emits an event. `zipWith` does not work for me, since it waits until both streams has an event to emit. `mergeWith` also does not seem to work, since it expects both stream to be from the same type.
Any hints would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is `combineLatest` operator

```
Observable<Foo> foo;
Observable<Bar> bar;

final output = Observable.combineLatest2(foo, bar, (Foo foo, Bar bar) {
  // TODO: somehow merge them
});
```

Comment: Nope, it is not applicable - taken from the **observable.dart** file - **The Observable will not emit until all streams have emitted at least one item.**, which does not comply with my requirements above, since I need to have this one fired when **either** of the streams emits an event.

Comment: @AngelTodorov Just push a `null` on the stream

Comment: Yeah, that did the trick. I will mark it as an answer, however, it  is a kind of a workaround - basically, I can use `zipWith` to achieve the very same result. I believe we need much cleaner method analogical to `mergeWith` but able to emit once either stream emits an event.

Comment: `zipWith` won't do. The combiner is called only after all streams submitted something. `combineLatest` combines the values after every single event (as long as there's an initial value). So `combineLatest` is much closer to `merge`

Comment: @RémiRousselet now with flutter null safety you can't push null in a non-null-emitting stream, then how can we apply this workaround now?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `Observable.race` ? it's perfect for notifications :

> Given two or more source streams, emit all of the items from only the first of these streams to emit an item or notification.

```
new Observable.race([
  new Observable.timer(1, new Duration(days: 1)),
  new Observable.timer(2, new Duration(days: 2)),
  new Observable.timer(3, new Duration(seconds: 1))
]).listen(print); // prints 3
```

learn more here https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/Observable/Observable.race.html

Comment: It will give events only for "winner" stream (which made first event) and discard events from others. See visualization: https://rxmarbles.com/#race

Answer (score 0):

Use [StreamGroup.merge](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/async/StreamGroup/merge.html) and check object type:

```dart
import 'package:async/async.dart';

Stream<MobileAdEvent> adEventStream;
Stream<Color> colorStream;

final merged = StreamGroup.merge([
  _orderStream.stream,
  _orderStream.stream.map((event) => event.hashCode),
]);

final subscription = merged.listen((event) {
  if (event is MobileAdEvent) {
    // handle event from first stream
  }
  if (event is Color) {
    // handle event from second stream
  }
});
```